# gjs cairo context drawing not displaying in clutter window

Tags: javascript, cairo, clutter

I'm trying to get a simple cairo drawing drawn to a clutter window using the javascript bindings.  My problem is, apart from half the functions being named slightly differently, is no matter what I try, the cairo drawing does not show up.  I used a example from python, which does work, and ported it to javascript.  I'm also using introspection to get the Clutter module instance.  I'm also using gjs version 0.7.14.  Can anyone tell me what is going wrong.

Below is the example code I'm using.

---

```
const cairo = imports.cairo;
const clutter =  imports.gi.Clutter;

function on_button_press_event (stage, event) {
    clutter.main_quit();
}

function draw(cairo_tex) {
    var context = cairo_tex.create();


    context.scale(200, 200);
    context.setLineWidth(0.1);
    var colour2 = new clutter.Color();
    colour2.from_string('#dd000088');
    clutter.cairo_set_source_color(context, colour2);
    context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
    context.arc(0, 0, 0.4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.stroke();
}

function main () {
    clutter.init(0, null);
    var stage = new clutter.Stage();
    var colour = new clutter.Color();
    colour.from_string("#ffccccff");
    stage.set_color(colour);
    stage.set_size(400, 300);
    stage.connect('button-press-event',  on_button_press_event);
    stage.connect('destroy', clutter.main_quit);

    var cairo_tex = new clutter.CairoTexture.new(200, 200);
    cairo_tex.set_position((stage.get_width() - 200) / 2,
                       (stage.get_height() - 200) / 2);

    draw(cairo_tex);


    var center_x = cairo_tex.get_width() / 2;
    var center_z = cairo_tex.get_height() / 2;
    cairo_tex.set_rotation(clutter.AlignAxis.Y_AXIS, 45.0, center_x, 0, center_z);
    stage.add_actor(cairo_tex);
    cairo_tex.show();

    stage.show();

    clutter.main();
}

main();
```

---

I think the reason this is not working has to do with the deletion of the cairo context in javascript.  context.destroy does not exist and using delete doesn't either.  Infact if I use delete then I get the warning

```
WARNING: 'applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is deprecated'
```

which does not help at all.  According to what some of the developers involved in gjs have posted about it, assigning to null should have the same effect, due to it being garbage collected.  I'm having my doubts as to whether there is anything to collect behind the scenes.

If someone could say if this is true or not, then I would accept this as a answer.

UPDATE:

I have narrowed down the problem area to imports.gi.Clutter.  I tried another example, but this time using Gtk instead of Clutter, and the following code actually works

```
cairo = imports.cairo;
Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
Gdk = imports.gi.Gdk;

function draw_arc(drawing_area){
    var cr = Gdk.cairo_create(drawing_area.get_window());

    cr.scale(2, 2);

    cr.operator = cairo.Operator.CLEAR;
    cr.paint();
    cr.operator = cairo.Operator.OVER;

    cr.setSourceRGB(0,255,0);
    cr.arc(128, 128, 76.8, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    cr.fill();

    return false;
}

Gtk.init(0, null);

var w = new Gtk.Window();
w.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit);

var d = new Gtk.DrawingArea();
w.add(d);

w.resize(500,600);
w.decorated = false;

d.connect('draw', draw_arc);

w.show_all();
Gtk.main();
```

This leads me to believe that the problem is not with the gjs implementation of cairo, but with the gjs introspection methods for Clutter Cairo implementation.  I'm thinking that clutter.CairoTexture.new or clutter.CairoTexture.create is not implemented properly.  I suspect it is the clutter.CairoTexture.create which is causing the problem.

Comment: I should also mention the library versions of the libraries are clutter 1.6.16 cairo 1.10.2-r1

Comment: `ClutterTexture` has been deprecated.  `ClutterImage` is the replacement, although for Cairo integration you may want to consider `ClutterCanvas`.

Comment: Have you gotten this to work in GJS as in Gnome-shell-extensions?  If so could you put it as an answer, as I'd love to close this one off?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, but I have gotten something to appear.  Give me a couple of days and I'll find some time to post up an answer to this.

Comment: That would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the newer integration between Clutter, and Cairo, specifically the `Clutter.Canvas` this will draw a circle to the screen:

```
const Clutter = imports.gi.Clutter;
const Cairo = imports.cairo;

const draw_stuff = function (canvas, cr, width, height) {
    cr.save ();
    cr.setOperator (Cairo.Operator.CLEAR);
    cr.paint ();
    cr.restore ();
    cr.setOperator (Cairo.Operator.OVER);
    cr.scale (width, height);
    cr.setLineCap (Cairo.LineCap.ROUND);
    cr.setLineWidth (0.1);

    cr.translate (0.5, 0.5);
    cr.arc (0, 0, 0.4, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    cr.stroke ();

    return true;
};

const test = function () {
    Clutter.init(null);

    let stage = new Clutter.Stage();
    stage.set_title ("Circle!");

    let color = new Clutter.Color({
        red : 255,
        green : 0,
        blue : 0,
        alpha : 128 // Just for the heck of it.
});
stage.set_background_color(color);
stage.set_size(300, 300);

let canvas = new Clutter.Canvas ();
canvas.set_size (155, 155);

let dummy = new Clutter.Actor ();
dummy.set_content (canvas);
dummy.set_size(155, 155);
stage.add_child (dummy);

stage.connect ("destroy", Clutter.main_quit);
canvas.connect ("draw", draw_stuff);
canvas.invalidate ();
stage.show_all();

Clutter.main ();
};

test ();
```

Comment: Thank you, while I didn't get an answer as to why it was failing before, and I don't expect you to know either, it's at least working now.  I've been waiting for over a year for something, event just a bone.  I feel I can close this, and I have.